# removing items on beforeSubmit callback in JQuery Form Plugin depending on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following codes which submit data on the server with ajax using JQUERY Form plugin:

```
initForm: function() {
                //submit form function
                var options = {
                    delegation: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
                        console.log(viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged);

                        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                            var obj = arr[j];
                            //always returns -1
                            if( viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged.indexOf(obj.value) != -1 ){
                                console.log('HERE');
                            }

                        }

                        $form.find( ".submit-button" ).button( "loading" );
                        $form.find( ".discount-value, .trucking" ).addClass( "uneditable-input" );
                        $form.find( ".discount-type" ).attr( "readonly", true );
                    },
                    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                        if ( responseText.status == "success" ) {
                            viewCtrl.modal.modal( "hide" );
                            $.growl.notice({ title: "<strong>Saved</strong>", message: responseText.message, size: "large", duration: 5000, location: "br" });
                        } else {
                            viewCtrl.modal.find( ".modal-content" ).html( responseText.form );
                        }

                        $form.find( ".submit-button" ).button( "reset" );
                    }
                };

                $( "#manage-products-form" ).ajaxForm( options );
},
```

Now i want to filter some items before submission. I want to remove items that are not in `viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged`. However, when i am checking if a particular item is in `viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged` it always returns `-1`. But i am certain that the item is there for i do a lot of `console.log()`.

These are what i logged

> viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged
>   [1899]

obj inside arr

> Object {name: "ci_inventorybundle_discountlevelitemcollectiontype[discountLevelItemProducts][0][variant]", value: "1899", type: "hidden", required: true}

What seems to be the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: In your beforeSubmit function how what kind of data is there in `obj` and `viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged`. Can you post some dummy data

Comment: @PrashantAgrawal i edited my question please see. Thanks.

Comment: @JCFrane i guess this is empty: `console.log(arr);`.......? can you confirm?

Comment: @PrashantAgrawal its not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array contains integer values but your `obj.value` is string. Try this.

```
if( viewCtrl.dliProductsChanged.indexOf(Number(obj.value)) != -1 ){
    console.log('HERE');
}
```